# PHP / PHP Unit / Artisan / Laravel restart app on next available port

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, phpunit

I have an integration test suit built using PHP unit running against a laravel app.
When the tests failed the app doesn't shutdown. When I run the tests again, it fails as the port is not available. I put some custom verification to ensure there is no app running on http://127.0.0.1:8000.
In case there is an app running there, I execute the following command `kill $(lsof -f -ti:8000)` which then kill the app running on that port. Great! Now the problem is, laravel/artisan starts a new app on the next available port within a range of 10, for instance, 8000 till 8010.

How can I stop this app which is started using `php artisan serve`?

PS. `CMD + C` or `CTRL + C` is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the serve command has a tries option that is set to 10 by default. I would imagine you can set this to 1 to achieve the result you’re after.
Have a look in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php` at the `getOptions` method.

So it looks like you can simply do `php artisan serve --port=8000 --tries=1`

Comment: Excellent! It works like a charm. Thanks @jon-white